# How to forward session through two servlets to jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, forwarding

I am trying to to forward data typed by user  and inserted on Database from the servlet responsable to insert data to database to the servlet that displays the database results to finally display it on jsp. I get an empty session in jsp. The user session attribut "sessionUtilisateur" works well but not the project attribut "projetdb".  What's wrong with my code?

Servlet for inserting data in DB:

```
private final static String VUE = "/Affichage"; 
private final static String ATT_MESSAGES = "messages";
private final static String ATT_SESSION = "sessionUtilisateur";


protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20 * 60);
    ConnectBDD test = new ConnectBDD();

    List<String> messages = test.insertNouveauProjet(request);
    String statut = test.testStatut(request);
    request.setAttribute("statut", statut);

    request.setAttribute(ATT_MESSAGES, messages);

    if (session.getAttribute(ATT_SESSION) == null) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Connexion");
    } else {
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Servlet for displaying data:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(20 * 60);
    ConnectBDD test = new ConnectBDD();

    List<Object> tachedb = test.selectTaches(request);
    String statut = test.testStatut(request);
    request.setAttribute("statut", statut);
    // Mettre les champs de formulaire de creation de projet dans un attribut

    // Mettre les messages de BDD dans un attribut
    List<Object> projetdb = test.selectDataProjet(request);

    if (session.getAttribute(ATT_SESSION) == null) {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Connexion");
    } else {
        session.setAttribute("tachedb", tachedb);
        session.setAttribute("projetdb", projetdb);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

JSP:

```
    <c:if test="${!empty sessionScope.sessionUtilisateur}">
        <p>${sessionScope.projetdb} </p>
    </c:if>
```

Comment: maybe `List<Object> projetdb = test.selectDataProjet(request);` returns null

Comment: The name for what you're looking for is called "flash" scope. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-flash-attribute-example/

Comment: @ScaryWombat when I use only the display servlet and jsp, it doesn't return null, it works perfectly but when I forward from inserting data servlet to display servlet it gets empty.

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku I never used Spring before. I will take a look thanks :)

Comment: @Lockman It's not a Spring-exclusive concept if I gave that impression, a lot of frameworks use it. It works at an abstraction level a bit over what you're doing here with straight Servlets.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of `test.selectDataProjet(request)`? Remember that the request object is the original request object sent to the insert servlet, which is likely in a different state than the request you use to hit the display servlet directly. You may need to wrap it before forwarding to contain the necessary parameters. Also, consider not passing an object of the HTTP layer (`request`) to your data access layer (`test`) - I can't imagine that it actually needs the whole request object.

Comment: @Tap you were totally right, one of my parameters necessary to select data from DB was returning null because I didn't contain it through the servlet to forward it. Now I have put this parameter in a session attribute and it worked :) Here's the modification in the servlet and the implementation of selectDataProjet(request).

Comment: if (session.getAttribute(ATT_SESSION) == null) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/Connexion");
        } else {
  
            session.getAttribute("cellreq");
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
        }

Comment: public List<Object> selectDataProjet(HttpServletRequest request) {
           // ConnexionUtilisateur userConnect = new ConnexionUtilisateur();
            //Utilisateur utilisateur = userConnect.connecterUtilisateur(request);
           HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            String cellule = (String) session.getAttribute("cellreq");
         PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        Connection connexion = null;
        String selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM Projets WHERE cellule = ?;";

Comment: @ThisIsNoZaku Oh okay I see, I'm gonna take time to read from the link you sent me. I am very new to Java EE :)